# Ajax call inside a dialog box with dialog close not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am fairly new to jQuery and Javascript. My issue is with jQuery UI dialog box. I have table where I click on a row and it populates further details into dialog box. Dialog will have a form and a table inside it. When a user enters details and clicks on the form I check for User inputs and display the form back into the dialog again, however when that happens dialog close button do not work.

Can someone suggest on how to approach this please? Thank you for the help.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"html",
    url:"form/add/"+estimateId,
    cache:false,
    //data:a,
    success:function(html){
        //alert(html);
        $(".projectMaintenance").html(html);
        $(".projectMaintenance").dialog({
            resizable:false,
            height:750,
            width:900,
            modal:true,
            buttons:{
                "Close":function(){
                    $(this).dialog('destroy');
    ....
```

This is the script i use to submit the form inside the dialog.

```
var a=$('form').serialize();

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"html",
    url:"form/save",
    cache:false,
    data:a,
    success:function(html){
        alert(html);
        $(".projectMaintenance").html(html);
.......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just execute the ajax request at user select the close option, to keep a little more readable and friendly, create a trySend() function

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"html",
        url:"form/add/"+estimateId,
        cache:false,
        //data:a,
        success:function(html){
            //handle if everything it's ok and should show the dialog....
            $(".projectMaintenance").html(html);
            $(".projectMaintenance").dialog({
                resizable:false,
                height:750,
                width:900,
                modal:true,
                buttons:{

                    "Close":function(){


                        $(this).dialog('destroy');


                        buttons: {
                            "Close": function () {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                                trySend();
                            }
                        }
```

.............

And the trySend function

```
        function trySend(){
            var a=$('form').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                dataType:"html",
                url:"form/save",
                cache:false,
                data:a,
                success:function(html){
                    alert(html);

                    $(".projectMaintenance").html(html);
                });
        }
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the delay. i followed the way you suggested and it works fine now.